# Can't make API calls to model endpoint deployed on AWS Sagemaker

Tags: python, image, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

We have trained a Nasnet model, and deployed the model as an endpoint on AWS Sagemaker successfully. When loading in the model locally, predictions can be made, but I'm not sure the format to pass in images when calling the API endpoint.

For reference, when loaded using tf.keras.load_model, the model's input is as follows:

```
[<tf.Tensor 'input_2:0' shape=(None, 331, 331, 3) dtype=float32>]
```

In addition, here is the function used to build the model, containing the model's predict_signature_def

```
def build(loaded_model, export_dir):
    build = builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_dir)
    print("INPUT FORMAT:")
    print(loaded_model.input)
    signature = predict_signature_def(inputs={"inputs": loaded_model.input}, outputs={"score": loaded_model.output})
    with K.get_session() as sess:
        # Save the meta graph and variables
        build.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
            sess=sess, tags=[tag_constants.SERVING], signature_def_map={"serving_default": signature})
        build.save()
```

We've tried making API calls to the endpoint in the following format:

```
    client = boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker',
    region_name='us-east-1',
    aws_access_key_id='ACCESS_KEY',
    aws_secret_access_key='SECRET_KEY')


    with open("kitchen.jpg", "rb") as image:
        f = image.read()
        b = bytearray(f)


    response = client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName='ENDPOINT_NAME_HERE',
    Body=b)
```

We tried multiple passing multiple formats for an image in the body (bytearray, base64, numpy array). However, we keep getting the same error from AWS:

```
Received client error (415) from model with message "{"error": "Unsupported Media Type: Unknown"}".
```

Does anyone know what the proper image input format should be, or have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Don't you need to specify `ContentType`? It seems the sagemaker does not know what media type is your binary body which you pass to it.

Comment: Hi Marcin, I added in ContentType of "application/x-image" when calling the invoke_endpoint function, and followed the same format as the docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/neo-requests.html. However, I'm getting the error "{"error": "Unsupported Media Type: application/x-image"}".

Comment: I'm wondering what I should change in order to accept application/x-image (such as redeploying the model), or whether another ContentType would be more appropriate? Thanks

Comment: You'll have to send correct content type. If the model can really read jpeg, send "Content-Type: image/jpeg". Otherwise you'll have to convert the image to whatever the model supports.